# How can I make HTMX display a 403 error page returned from a hx-delete request?

Tags: htmx

In my project, when the web browser submits a hx-delete request, and the backend determines the user doesn't have the required permissions for that request, the backend returns a full 403 error page. By default HTMX ignores this response. I would like HTMX to instead display the full 403 error page.

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't think you should "display" the 403 page itself, for normal requests it should redirect you to 200 page with an error message. The way I solved it was by creating custom permission decorator for htmx request and then set `HX-Redirect` to a specific error page whenever 403 was caught. I can provide more code examples, if you're using django.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding this code to the page.

```js
/***
 * Swaps in the body of error pages returned from htmx requests 
 */
document.addEventListener("htmx:beforeOnLoad", function (event) {
    const xhr = event.detail.xhr
    if (xhr.status == 500 || xhr.status == 403 || xhr.status == 404) {
        event.stopPropagation() // Tell htmx not to process these requests
        document.children[0].innerHTML = xhr.response // Swap in body of response instead
    }
})
```

Comment: hm. but you don't swap into the htmx response div, but into the pages children[0], which is `<body>`...

Comment: Maybe it'd be better to use `event.target.innerHTML` instead of `document.children[0].innerHTML`

Comment: @nerdoc You could definitely do that - HTMX is quite malleable. In this case, the outcome I wanted was to show a full error page, and replacing the body element is the way to do that.